# how to skip bracket from the name in HTML data attribute jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, attributes

HTML part

```
 <button class="add_cart btn-success btn-block"  data-productname="<?php echo $row->item_name;?>"  >Add To Cart</button>
```

JQuery  part

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.add_cart').click(function(){

       var product_name  = $(this).data("productname");



 $.ajax({
        url : "<?php echo site_url('Product/add_to_cart');?>",
        method : "POST",
        data : {product_name: product_name},
         success: function(data){
                      $('#detail_cart').html(data);
                           }
        });
     });
 });
```

according to the above code (codeigniter view file code)
Here, We were using html data attribute to get the product name from html and pass the product name into jquery ajax,That product name came from database.

> The Error is that product name (which fetch from db) some of product name is perfectly working fine to ajax and some of may not 
>   product name contain bracket that name we can't access by ajax.
>   example

[image: db photo]

1,3 is working fine and access by ajax

Comment: `data-productname="'<?php echo $row->item_name;?>'"`?

Comment: codeigniter shopping cart class doesn't allow any special character in the name.

Comment: Thank you for your response @YadhuBabu , Ok then How to solve that issue ?

Comment: Just wondering why you wouldn't be passing the items id instead of its name if you are using that to add something to a database?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw Thank you for you response.Ya you are but I want know if there simple way to sort it <3

Answer (score 0):

You can alter the product name rule after creating My_Cart.php 
  in application\libraries  with this code:

```
 var $product_name_rules = '\d\D';
```

See this link for more options

http://ponderwell.net/2010/07/codeigniter-extending-the-cart-class-for-robust-product-names/